# What is the best Method to Sync Application data

Tags: android

I am searching for the best way to Sync data from application. By data I mean I want to get updated data from server and send User data to server.
I am aware of SyncAdapter. but I cant run multiple Instances of SyncAdapter. I do not want to download all the data at once. I just want to download data that I would need in next Activity so that User doesn't have to wait in next Activity.
Can Anybody suggest me on how I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

SyncAdapter isn't about "downloading all the data at once". Please take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE. SyncAdapter is a way of "refreshing" data in your local database. Content provider "wraps" around your database and gives your application data (through for example Cursor Adapter)...

Also you should do "Lazy load" instead of "I just want to download data that I would need in next Activity so that User doesn't have to wait in next Activity".

Hope i helped.

Comment: Thanks for the video.
I will get back to you after watching the video.